# How to identify which button is pressed and send that to server?

Tags: php, html

In the while loop I have doctor name, specialist and payment from my database. Each doctor has an `<input type="button">` named "did". I want that when I press a button to contact a specific doctor, the value of `$row3['did']` will sent to my `contact.php` page. But I cannot understand where to put it in the `<input type="button">` so that I can identify which button is pressed and send its value to `contact.php`.

```
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{       
        ?>      
        <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
        <div class="title-img">
        <div class="title"><img src="images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif" alt=""></div>
        <!--<div class="title-desc"><p>FACILITY 1</p></div>-->
        <div class="clear"></div> 
        </div>
        <h4 class=head>Doctor name: <?php echo $row3['dName'];?></h4>
        <p>Specialist: <?php echo $row3['specialist'];?></p>
        <p>Payment: <?php echo $row3['payment'];?></p>


        <hr>

            <div id='contact-form'>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">more</a>

                <!--<button id="findHelp" class="btn btn-primary"><a href="?did=<?php// echo $row3['did'];?>"  >Find help</a></button>-->
                <!--<a href="data/contact.php?did=<?php //echo $row3['did'];?>"  ></a>-->
                <!--<input type='button' name='contact' id='contact' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>-->

                <form method='post' action='contact.php'>
                    <input type='button' name='did' id='did' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary'/>
                </form>


            </div>

            <!-- preload the images -->
            <div style='display:none'>
                <img src='images/loading.gif' alt='' />
            </div>

        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add the form..simply send the id with link when button is clicked and get that id on contact .php page..

OR use as following

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.contact').click(function(){
            var this_rel=$(this).attr('rel');
            location.href="contact.php?id="+this_rel;
       });
    });
</script>


 <input type='button' name='did' id='did' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary' rel="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>
```

Comment: where I have to put the link?

Comment: It gets the value "Message" not "$row3['did']".

Comment: yes i passed the dynamic id in rel attribute..but u can pass that in value too but in jquery you have to change rel to val.

Comment: how can i do that?sorry for awkward ques.

Comment: i added one more answer for your clerification

Answer (score 0):

try `if(isset($_POST['button_name']) && $_POST['button_name'] === 'button_value')`

Comment: every button has the value "Message" which is shown in the button.but need to send the value $row3['did'].

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden value inside the form, and assign the doctor details there

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">

   <input type="hidden" name="thedoctor" value="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>  
   <input type="button" name="did" id="did" value="Message" class="contact demo btn btn-primary"/>

</form>
```

And then find the selected button by `$button_clicked =  $_POST['thedoctor']`

Comment: it cannot hold different values.

Comment: What do you mean? From my example, $button_clicked will be the id of the doctor relating to the button selected - this is what your question asks. Actually try what I've suggested.

Comment: i tried like this way earlier.but it does not work .every time it holds the first value of my database.

Answer (score 0):

This will be your PHP code

```
<?php
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{       
        ?>      
        <div class="col_1_of_4 span_1_of_4">
        <div class="title-img">
        <div class="title"><img src="images/Crystal_Clear_user.gif" alt=""></div>
        <!--<div class="title-desc"><p>FACILITY 1</p></div>-->
        <div class="clear"></div> 
        </div>
        <h4 class=head>Doctor name: <?php echo $row3['dName'];?></h4>
        <p>Specialist: <?php echo $row3['specialist'];?></p>
        <p>Payment: <?php echo $row3['payment'];?></p>


        <hr>

            <div id='contact-form'>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">more</a>


                    <input type='button' name='did' id='did' value="Message" class='contact demo btn btn-primary' rel="<?php echo $row3['did'];?>"/>


            </div>

            <!-- preload the images -->
            <div style='display:none'>
                <img src='images/loading.gif' alt='' />
            </div>

        </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

and above that put some jquery code

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.contact').click(function(){
            var this_rel=$(this).attr('rel');
            location.href="contact.php?id="+this_rel;
       });
    });
</script>
```

Dont forget to write query of database, because that was not in your example, thats why i did not mention that. Also add jquery.js to its appropriate place so jquery code can run. Please do this trick and let me know..

Answer (score 0):

Just use `buttons` :

## HTML

```
<form method="POST">
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_1" value="abc">Message</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_1" value="def">Message</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_1" value="ghi">Message</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_1" value="jkl">Message</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_2" value="123">Message</button>
    <button type="submit" name="btn_action_3" value="456">Message</button>
</form>
```

## PHP

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['btn_action_1'])) {
        echo 'btn_action_1 was pressed with value: '. $_POST['btn_action_1'];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['btn_action_2'])) {
        echo 'btn_action_2 was pressed with value: '. $_POST['btn_action_2'];
    }
```